# Why do electrons or other plasma species follow Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution in plasma?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, plasma-physics, gas

In plasma physics why do electrons and other plasma species follow maxwell boltzmann distribution?
Is there any physical reason behind it or simply becoz most plasmas follow classical physics.

Comment: This is a linguistics question rather than a physics one.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quasi

Comment: I agree with @NiharKarve.

Comment: I got the meaning!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about Physics

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, but too broad. Main reason is that a lot of things in Physics and in other nature disciplines (chemistry, biology, etc) are following a [normal_distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). So you should be asking why nature follows a normal distribution of some values ? Simplest answer would be, that nature at macro level is deterministic. So one can have an **expected value** of some measure $\langle x \rangle$. If you'll add fluctuation to that $\langle x \rangle+\delta x$, then you'll get a change in probability too for measuring such deviation : $\delta P = \delta P(\langle x \rangle,\delta x)$. But as for, why nature decreases *exponentially* this probability of finding exact fluctuation dispersed from the mean - remains the question to me. Well, in some way exponential dropping means "expected value centric", which is another wording to say that we live in a deterministic world.